# How to fix error checked by Parasoft

Tags: c, parasoft

In my source code (in C), there is a line as below:

```
char line[1000] = "";
fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)
```

When I use parasoft to check, I receive two error:

```
In 'fgets' function call, do not pass long casted to int expression as '2' function argument
The type 'unsigned long' of function argument number '2' does not match declared type 'int'
```

I find nothing wrong with these lines in source code, so I don't know how to fix these error. Could you please give me a suggestion?

Comment: The prototype of fgets is `char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );` and apparently on your platform the type of the `sizeof` operator is `unsigned long`. Check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) is accepting an `int` for its second parameter. (IMHO, this is a defect)

`sizeof` returns a value of type `size_t`, which in your case seems to be an alias of `unsigned Iong`. The issue with this is that an `unsigned long` can be (much) too large to be convertible to an `int`.

There's not much you can do about it here. To get rid of the error you might use a cast:

```
fgets(line, (int)sizeof(line), file);
```

Note that your use of `sizeof` might get you into trouble if at some point you decide to change that array into a dynamically allocated one or if you refractor the code into different functions.

Comment: i think it was tagged C, not C++ so (int)

Comment: @AndersK. Indeed, fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What product are you using? If you are using C++test you can go to the quality tasks view for the violation that is being reported and right click on the violation and select "View Rule Documentation" That explains why the violation is being thrown and gives you an example on how to fix the violation.